# GCP Cloud Run - Unable to hide seret value from the GCP's revision history tab when passing secret using a Terraform resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run

I deployed a `GCP` `CloudRun` service using a `Terraform resource` [`google_cloud_run_service`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service).

The image is using [`grafana/synthetic-monitoring-agent`](https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/synthetic-monitoring-agent) and a `secret`(`PROBE_API_TOKEN`) needs to be passed as an `argument`. The `secret` is stored in `GCP`'s `secret manager` and is passed and called as `data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.probe_api_token.secret_data`

The `args` attribute from the Terraform resource(`google_cloud_run_service`) is set as below

```
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "${data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.probe_api_token.secret_data}", "--verbose", "true", "--debug"]
```

The above method works as the correct secret value (`PROBE_API_TOKEN`) is passed. However, from the `GCP console`, I'm able to see the `secret` in clear text from the `revision history` tab.

In order to hide the secret, I've tried using [`secret_key_ref`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#args:%7E:text=The-,secret_key_ref,-block%20supports%3A) attribute from the `Terraform resource`(`google_cloud_run_service`) and tried referencing the `secret` from the `environment variable` -  since the `secret` is set as an `environment variable` - but  `CloudRun` does not seem to read the correct secret.

Here's the args attribute used for this approach. `$$` is used instead of a single`$` as the latter throws an error.

```
  args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "$${PROBE_API_TOKEN}", "--verbose", "true", "--debug"]
```

Is there a way to hide or encrypt the token from the `GCP` console's `revision history` tab?

Thank you!

Update:

Here are more commands I've tried. None of these seem to work

```
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token $$PROBE_API_TOKEN"]
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "${PROBE_API_TOKEN}"]
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "$$PROBE_API_TOKEN"]
args = ["--api-server-address ${var.probe_api_server_url} --api-token $$PROBE_API_TOKEN"]
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "$(PROBE_API_TOKEN)", "--verbose", "true", "--debug"]
args = ["--api-server-address=${var.probe_api_server_url} --api-token=$$PROBE_API_TOKEN"]
args = ["--api-server-address=${var.probe_api_server_url}", "--api-token=$$PROBE_API_TOKEN"]
args = ["--api-server-address=${var.probe_api_server_url}", "--api-token=$(PROBE_API_TOKEN)"]
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "$${PROBE_API_TOKEN}", "--verbose", "true", "--debug"]
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "$PROE_API_TOKEN", "--verbose", "true", "--debug"]
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "$PROE_API_TOKEN", "--verbose", "true", "--debug"]
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url, "--api-token", "$PROBE_API_TOKEN", "--verbose", "true", "--debug"]
```

Sreenshot:

[image]

`YAML` from GCP Console

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: private-probe-int
  namespace: <namespace>
  selfLink: <selflink>
  uid: <uid>
  resourceVersion: <version>
  generation: 22
  creationTimestamp: '2022-04-20T16:16:20.595165Z'
  labels:
    cloud.googleapis.com/location: us-east4
  annotations:
    serving.knative.dev/creator: <server>
    serving.knative.dev/lastModifier: <server>
    run.googleapis.com/ingress: all
    run.googleapis.com/ingress-status: all
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: private-probe
      annotations:
        autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale: '1'
        run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-egress: all-traffic
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '100'
        run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-connector: us-east4
    spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      timeoutSeconds: 60
      serviceAccountName: <serviceaccount>
      containers:
      - image: <url>
        args:
        - --api-server-address
        - synthetic-monitoring-grpc-eu-west.grafana.net:443
        - --api-token
        - <API TOKEN IN CLEAR TEXT>
        - --verbose
        - 'true'
        - --debug
        ports:
        - name: http1
          containerPort: 4050
        env:
        - name: CONTAINER_TAG
          value: latest
        - name: PROBE_API_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: latest
              name: PROBE_API_TOKEN
        - name: CONTAINER_NAME
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 256Mi
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Secret Manager for Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets)?

Comment: @RobertG yes, that is what I'm currently using. The secret is being called from the secret manager using the command `data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.probe_api_token.secret_data`

Comment: I've already created a sample project based on the documentation that you provided however I wasn't able to find any secret value on my end. Can you also provide a screenshot of your logs/revision history/YAML where your secret value is being shown? Just omit any sensitive information so that it would not be shown publicly.

Comment: @RobertG I've added the screenshot of the revision history and the YAML. The secret is not shown in the logs. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using a similar approach that was suggested as a solution by [Danyel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044583/danyel-cabello). I used a `Dockerfile` `build args` to pass a `token` and used an `ENTRYPOINT` to trigger a `command`.

e.g.

```
FROM grafana/synthetic-monitoring-agent:latest
ARG PROBE_API_TOKEN
ENV PROBE_API_TOKEN=${PROBE_API_TOKEN}

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/synthetic-monitoring-agent --api-token  $PROBE_API_TOKEN --api-server-address synthetic-monitoring-grpc-eu-west.grafana.net:443 --verbose true --debug"]
```

The token is no longer visible from the GCP console.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an internal shell script in your Docker container and use the env variables inside of it

`/app/start.sh`

Remember to add execute permissions to your new script `chmod +x /app/start.sh`, then in your new script you can call your original command with values from Cloud Run args and use the env variables

```
#!/bin/sh
<original_command> "$@" --api-token $PROBE_API_TOKEN
```

And in your terraform script

`main.tf`

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        env {
          name = "PROBE_API_TOKEN"
          value_from {
            secret_key_ref {
              name = <secert_name>
              key = <secret_key>
            }
          }
        }
        image = <url>
        command = ["/app/start.sh"]
args = ["--api-server-address", var.probe_api_server_url,  "--verbose", "true", "--debug"]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've tried this method but I can't seem to pass the file as `/app/start.sh`

I've tried adding the shell script file locally but getting the below error - 
`terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /application/run.sh: no such file or directory`

I've also tried using the terraform's `local_file` resource but got the same error. Does Cloud Run not take a local script to be passed as a command?

The `google_cloud_run_service` command attributes is:
`command = ["${path.module}/application/run.sh"]`

Comment: Update: I was able to solve the issue by having the commands inside the `Dockerfile` and passed the `PROBE_API_TOKEN` as a Docker build arg. The token is no longer being displayed from the GCP console